# Glassfish Grizzly FilterChain vs WebSocketApplication

Tags: websocket, glassfish, grizzly

What is the difference for FilterChain and WebSocketApplication? From what I understand, FilterChain are processors that transforms the state of a message and WebSocketApplication is an interface that processes incoming message. Both sounds like they process messages. What is the difference here?